# ICEBP assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, breakpoints

As a workaround with x86 instructions, I used an opcode looks like `.byte 0xf1, 0xc1` and tried to execute that inside gdb. the disassembly of that line shows

```
f1      icebp
```

So, when first byte which is F1 is fetched it is recognized as an instruction called `icebp`. This is known to be an undocumented instruction. The only thing I found in the SDM, is a footnote in INT sections saying

```
The mnemonic ICEBP has also been used for the instruction with opcode F1
```

Continuing with gdb, it says

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x1ffffc20
```

So, what is that address? How it is generated? Is it physical or virtual? and how can I test its real functionality?

UPDATE:

GDB operations are shown below:

```
(gdb) list
1       void main()
2       {
3         __asm__(".byte 0xf1, 0xc1");
4       }
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) disass /r main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004ed <+0>:     55      push   rbp
   0x00000000004004ee <+1>:     48 89 e5        mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000004004f1 <+4>:     f1      icebp
   0x00000000004004f2 <+5>:     c1 5d c3 66     rcr    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x3d],0x66
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f3: file machine2.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mahmood/Documents/./machine2

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00000000004004f2 in main () at machine2.c:2
2       {
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x4004f2 <main+5>:   rcr    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x3d],0x66
(gdb) n
Cannot access memory at address 0x1ffffc20
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x4004f5:    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

UDPATE2:

After removing `c1`, the debugger is not able to set the breakpoint at the asm line.

```
(gdb) list
1       void main()
2       {
3         __asm__(".byte 0xf1");
4       }
(gdb) b machine2.c:3
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f2: file machine2.c, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mahmood/Documents/./machine2

Breakpoint 1, main () at machine2.c:4
4       }
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: `icebp` is also more widely known in the ISA as [`Int1`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1). It is 1 byte method of generating a debug exception. It is generally used for hardware level debugging. `ICEBP` is how AT&T assembly refers to it.

Comment: Yes. I also have read collins page about that. The question is, now my haswell wants to execute this instruction. How it is going to execute that? ICE debug is for professionals.

Comment: When you say continue in GDB you mean you let the program keep going aftre the trap? If so then the `Cannot access memory at address 0x1ffffc20` will be because of an instruction somewhere after the breakpoint. Did you review the instruction that caused that error? If this is running in Linux userspace that is a virtual address.

Comment: What was the `0xc1` suppose to represent?

Comment: In GDB use `x/i $pc` to see what instruction caused the memory error.

Comment: The program is one liner and there is no other instruction. That is `__asm__ (".byte 0xf1, 0xc1");`

Comment: What I don't understand is what the 0xc1 is. I asked that before. That will form part of the next instruction after the breakpoint but isn't an instruction by itself. In fact it became part of the `c1 5d c3 66     rcr` instruction (first byte). Why are you placing 0xc1 in the code after the 0xf1?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that `5d c3` in itself is `pop rbp` `ret` which would appear to be the epilogue of a function. The 0xc1 appears to have turned that into an RCR instruction that is made up of the bytes from the `pop rbp` , `ret` and data after. Basically you had the processor do a rather nonsensical instruction that just so happened to contain a bogus memory reference. You might have better luck removing the 0xc1 after the 0xf1, unless you have some specific reasoning for putting it in there. To me I am stumped as to what `0xc1` is intended to do after `icebp`

Comment: I was playing with an add instruction which was `01 c1`. I removed that. The assembly code now looks different. However, I am not able to set a breakpoint at the asm line.

Comment: By executing the code from the terminal I see `Trace/breakpoint trap` in the output and the program terminates normally.

Comment: GDB is intercepting the Trap caused by `icebp`. Let me ask a better question. Are you using hardware debugger or are you just trying to get a software breakpoint set? If you just want a software break point why not the `int3` instruction? It has now become unclear why you are using `icebp` at all especially since you are are able to set software breakpoints in GDB.

Comment: If your debugger supports TUI mode (likely if you are on Linux), use `layout asm` and you can step through the assembly instructions with `si`. I almost wonder if you are doing all this to step through individual assembly instructions rather than the C statements? This almost smells like an XY problem. I'd be curious exactly what your original problem was. Maybe if we knew what lead you down this path in the first place maybe we can find a better solution for your actual problem.

Comment: I just wanted to try to see what happens if some undefined opcodes are feed to the processor. For that, I created a C file and intended to put one assembly line. As I tried F1, I saw that it is icebp which is undocumented but don't know how to use it and what is going to be solved with this instruction...

Comment: Int1 (icebp) is poorly documented but not undefined. If you want to raise an #UD (undefined opcode exception), what about [`ud2`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ud)?