# Are the cmpxchg esp, eax instructions the same as the icebp instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819296/icebp-assembly-instruction), we know that `icebp` instruction is similiar like `int1` instruction.

In this case, I'm doing such a stupid experiment like comparing and exchange without a input :

```
global _start
section .text

_start:

cmpxchg esp, eax
```

Build with : `nasm -f elf example.asm && ld -o example example.o`

When I do debugging, the instruction it will execute the `icebp` instruction

```
% gdb -q cmpxchg
Reading symbols from cmpxchg...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
gdb-peda$ r
Starting program: /home/user/assembly/cmpxchg 

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.

[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0xbfffee18 --> 0x3fffcc2b 
EBX: 0x0 
ECX: 0x0 
EDX: 0x0 
ESI: 0x0 
EDI: 0x0 
EBP: 0x0 
ESP: 0xbfffee00 --> 0x1 
EIP: 0x8048093 --> 0x12ff
EFLAGS: 0x206 (carry PARITY adjust zero sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x804808e:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
   0x8048090:   add    al,0x0
   0x8048092:   icebp  
=> 0x8048093:   call   DWORD PTR [edx]
   0x8048095:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
   0x8048097:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
   0x8048099:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
   0x804809b:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
No argument
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xbfffee00 --> 0x1 
0004| 0xbfffee04 --> 0xbffff013 ("/home/user/assembly/cmpxchg")
0008| 0xbfffee08 --> 0x10 
0012| 0xbfffee0c --> 0xbffff044 ("XDG_SEAT=seat0")
0016| 0xbfffee10 --> 0xbffff053 ("XDG_SESSION_ID=c2")
0020| 0xbfffee14 --> 0xbffff065 ("LC_IDENTIFICATION=id_ID.UTF-8")
0024| 0xbfffee18 --> 0x3fffcc2b 
0028| 0xbfffee1c --> 0xbffff0a6 ("DISPLAY=:0")
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value
Stopped reason: SIGTRAP
0x08048093 in ?? ()
gdb-peda$
```

My question is, how did it happen?

Comment: No, they're not similar, and I can't reproduce your result; `0f b1 c4` shows up in GDB 8.3.1 as `0x8049000       cmpxchg esp,eax` in a 32-bit statically linked Linux executable built with NASM + ld from `echo "cmpxchg esp, eax" > foo.asm`.  (I'm using plain GDB, not gdb-peda).  **Show the machine code (GDB `disas /r`) and/or source + build commands to make this a [mcve]**.  I wonder if somehow you're seeing disassembly of a software breakpoint that GDB set?

Comment: Your result isn't even plausible; the `call` is only 2 bytes after the `add`, meaning that the `icebp` is only 1 byte long (as expected for [F1 opcode, ` int1` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1)).  Unless there are other bugs throwing off your GDB's address counting/printing, there's no way this is just a software breakpoint on top of `cmpxchg` getting disassembled.

Comment: I mean, when the instruction is executed it will execute the `icebp` instruction (edited question)

Comment: No, that's not possible.  `cmpxchg esp,eax` is 3 bytes long so it's not possible that your GDB output is showing disassembly for machine code containing that instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's a bug ? or ....

Comment: Unlikely, but show a [mcve] of your source + how you built it, then maybe we can explain how you ended up with `00 00`  (add [eax],al) `04 00` (add al,0x0) and `f1` (icebp / int1) machine code in whatever you're executing.  None of those byte are part of the encoding for `cmpxchg`.  Is that even the `.text` section of your executable?  Or did you somehow jump to .rodata?

Comment: Edited, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to single-step to see the `cmpxchg esp, eax`  instruction execute.  **Execution went way beyond that until it happened to hit an `f1` opcode.**

Use `starti` to start at the first user-space instruction, then `si`.

Normally your process will segfault if you let execution fall into a bunch of `00 00` bytes, because that decodes as `add [eax], al` and EAX=0 at the start of a Linux static executable.  (You didn't bother to make an `_exit` system call from your `_start`.)

**But [`cmpxchg esp, eax`](http://Compare%20EAX%20with%20r/m32.%20If%20equal,%20ZF%20is%20set%20and%20r32%20is%20loaded%20into%20r/m32.%20Else,%20clear%20ZF%20and%20load%20r/m32%20into%20EAX.) sets EAX to a valid pointer.**  (The implicit operand EAX wasn't equal to ESP initially, so "*clear ZF and load r/m32 into EAX*" happens.  The fact that EAX was given as the explicit source operand is irrelevant, BTW.)

Execution continues through a bunch of `00` instructions that decode as `00 00` add.  Then gets to the block you show, where **the first instruction that faults happens to be an `f1` byte that was sitting there in the executable somewhere after the end of the `.text` section.**

---

Of course `cmpxchg` doesn't execute as `icebp` / `int1`.  And your disassembly isn't even possible if you were *actually* at the cmpxchg instruction.  That `cmpxchg` is 3 bytes long, but the distance between addresses for adjacent instructions is only 1 byte.  So it can't possibly be GDB mis-decoding it.